# JavaScript - Delay execution of certain javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, delayed-execution

I need help in delaying the execution of my javascript.(not making the javascript to execute right after the webpage is being loaded) I wish to execute the javascript only after 10s after the webpage is being loaded. How can I do that? This is the script.

```
    <script>
    var interval = 10000;
    var current_index = -1;
    var sales_feeds = [];
    var showtime = 5000;
        <?php $s = get_option('wc_feed_delay_between_popups_appear');
        if (!$s) { 

          $s = 5000;
        }
        ?>
    function hide_prev_feed_notify(index)
    {
        if( sales_feeds.eq(current_index).length > 0 )
        {
            sales_feeds.eq(current_index).animate({bottom: '-90px'}, 500);
        }
    }
    function show_live_feed_notify(index)
    {
        sales_feeds.eq(index).animate({bottom: '10px'}, 1000);

        current_index = index;
    }
    function show_next_live_notify()
    {
        if( (current_index + 1) >= sales_feeds.length )
        {
            current_index = -1;
        }

        //add randomness 
        current_index = (Math.floor(Math.random() * (sales_feeds.length + 1))) - 1;;

        if( window.console )
            console.log('will show ' + (current_index+1));

          show_live_feed_notify(current_index + 1);
          setTimeout(function() { hide_prev_feed_notify(current_index + 1); }, showtime);
    }
    function stop_live_notify()
    {
        removeInterval(inverval);
    }
    function readCookie(name) 
    {
        var nameEQ = escape(name) + "=";
        var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) 
        {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0) === ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
            if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) === 0) return unescape(c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length));
        }
        return null;
    }
    jQuery(function()
    {
        jQuery('.wc_feed_close_btn').click(function()
        {
            var days = 30;
            var date = new Date();
            date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days *24 *60 *60 *1000));
            if(window.console)
                console.log(date.toGMTString());
            document.cookie = 'wc_feed_closed=true; expires=' + date.toGMTString() + ';';
            jQuery('.live-sale-notify').css('display', 'none');
            clearInterval(interval);
            return false;
        });

        sales_feeds = jQuery('.live-sale-notify');

        show_next_live_notify();
        interval = setInterval(show_next_live_notify, (showtime + <?php print $s + 100; ?>));
    });
    </script>
```

Note: I want to delay the following execution.

```
    function show_live_feed_notify(index)
{
    sales_feeds.eq(index).animate({bottom: '10px'}, 1000);

    current_index = index;
}
```

I tried inserting

```
    var delay = 10000;
```

or

```
    var interval = 10000;
```

none of them seem to work.

I also tried

```
    setTimeout (function(); 3000);
```

it came out with uncaught syntax error. 
Please Help me guys!

Note: I'm new to js/php coding...

Comment: Why are you using php here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code, I think you should just remove the line

```
show_next_live_notify();
```

at the bottom of your script. It automatically executes everything right upon start instead of letting `setInterval` do its job

To delay the whole script, replace the last two lines in the jQuery call with something like this:

```
function startMe() {
   interval = setInterval(show_next_live_notify, (showtime + <?php print $s + 100; ?>));
}

setTimeout(startMe, 10000);
```

Comment: Thanks. But I would like to delay the script instead of making it executes right upon the webpage is reloaded. i wish to delay it by 10s. The whole script.

Comment: Thats exactly what my suggestion would do. But If you also want the `setInterval` to be delayed for whatever reason, you should remove the last line of your code  `(interval = setInterval(show_next_live_notify, (showtime + <?php print $s + 100; ?>));` and replace it with something like this

Comment: function startMe() {

Answer (score 0):

You function name is show_live_feed_notify, and you tried to use setTimeout. Therefore I suggest you to try the following:

```
var delay = 10000; // 10 seconds
setTimeout(function() {
    show_live_feed_notify(current_index + 1);
}, delay )
```

Comment: I tried the code. unfortunately, the javascript still execute once the webpage is loaded. I wish to delay them by 10s. How can i do that?

Comment: 3000 is here the number of ms, so it's 3 seconds. It's probably because of the short delay that you think it's executed immediately on page loading. If you need 10 seconds then try the value 10000